# Sed find and replace

Tags: regex, sed

I need to amended the following text in a few hundred documents ...

```
{% url project.app.views.chart %}
```

so it reads

```
{% url "project.app.views.chart" %}
```

Do you know the next way to do this based on the text between the quotes being different each time ?

Thanks,

Comment: Different, how? Where does the replacement come from for a given file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

This works as soons as you don't have any `%` char in your input strings:

```
sed -r 's/url ([^%]+) %/url "\1" %/g'
```

**Test**

```
$ echo '{% url test %}{% url test 2 %}' | sed -r 's/url ([^%]+) %/url "\1" %/g'
{% url "test" %}{% url "test 2" %}
```

### Explanations

Let's explain this answer. The `-r` option is here because `extended regexes` are the one I prefer to use.

Now, the substitution part.

```
sed 's/pattern/replacement/g'
```

Is used to replace text, matching *pattern* as a `regular expression` and replacing it by *replacement*.

The `g` is a substitution option that means you want to replace the pattern as many times as it is present in the text.

So here the *pattern* is `url ([^%]+) %`. `url` and `%` part are pretty logical and easy to get (if not, tell me). The `([^%]+)` means *"capture everything that isn't a `%` and that is composed by at least a character"*. The parenthesis allow to save this part, to reuse it after with `\x` where x is the number of the parenthesis group (Here it will be `\1`).

So when it receives `{% url test %}`, the pattern matches `url test %` where `test` is saved under `\1`, and it rewrites it with `url "\1" %` so `url "test" %`.
The parts before and after the pattern aren't modified, so it will output `{% url "test" %}`

### Other possibilities

To avoid adding another set of quotes if there are already there, just add `[^"]` after `url` that way : `url [^"]`.

Here is the full command :

```
sed -r 's/url ([^"][^%]+) %/url "\1" %/g'
```

Comment: This works perfectly, can you maybe breakdown how this works ?

Comment: Thanks for all your help, Ive just spotted he problem where if there are already quotes then it added another pair.

Comment: @felix001 Then just add `[^"]` after `url ` that way : `url [^"]`

Comment: Its deletes of the first character i.e 
{% url "roject.app.views.chart" %}

Comment: Yes, just moving the parenthesis could be fine also.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to wrap string between `url` and `%}`.

Something like this may work:

```
sed -e 's/url /url "/' -e 's/ %}/" %}/'
```